# Getting a list of DL with less than 2 users

Tags: powershell

Good day,

I'm trying to create a list of all the DL in my company that has two or fewer users. There are a lot of DL that people just stop to use or are empty. We are trying to delete them. This is what I have but I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake. Thank you so much for your time.

```
$GroupList = Get-ADGroup -filter * -searchbase " Company's OU "

$List = foreach ($Group in $GroupList) {
    $MembersoftheGroups = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.Name
    foreach ($user in $MembersoftheGroups) {
        $Internal_counter = 0

        If ($user.objectClass -eq "user") {

            $Internal_counter++ 
        }  
        if ($Internal_counter -gt "2") { }  
        if ($Internal_counter -le "2") {
            $Property = @{
                Group = $Group.Name;

            }

            $newobject = New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $Property
            $newobject
        }  
    }
}

$List
```

Comment: You're going a step too far: `if ((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group.Name | ? objectClass -eq user).Count -le 2) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would handle getting a list of AD Groups containing two or fewer members:

```
$groups = ((Get-ADGroup -properties members -filter *) | ? { $_.Members.count -le 2 })
```

Comment: WOW!!!, I still have so much to learn. Is kinda funny how you guys are able to do what I want to do in one line. XD

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try....

```
$(Get-ADGroup -Filter { GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution' } -SearchBase '<whatever>').DistinguishedName | % { if ( $(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_).count -lt 3 ){ $_ } }
```

The filter in the call to `Get-ADGroup` will help performance. You'll end up with a list of distribution groups that have 2 members or less.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"' -Properties Members | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Members.Count -le 2 }
```

Bonus (Sort by count and format into a table):

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Distribution"' -Properties Members | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Members.Count -le 2 } |
        ForEach-Object -Process {
            [pscustomobject] @{
                Name = $_.Name
                MemberCount = $_.Members.Count
                Members = $_.Members
            }
        } | Sort-Object -Property MemberCount,Name | Format-Table -AutoSize
```